# Java: Initialize subclass member object after super()-call?

Tags: java

Let's assume I have two classes, Super and Sub. They look like this:

```
public class Super {
    private A a;
    private B b;

    public Super() {
        this.a = new A();
        this.b = new B();
    }
}

public class Sub extends Super {
    private C c;

    public Sub() {
        super();
        this.c = new C();
    }
}
```

If I now call the constructor of Sub, why doesn't `c` get initialized? Or should this work in general and there is another problem with my (actual) code?

Comment: What? It very much does get initialized. What's your evidence?

Comment: Please post some code that reproduces your problem.

Comment: c is initialized with this line this.c = new C();

Comment: Also there is no need to explicitly call `super()`, that call will be inserted by the compiler.

Comment: I don't see a problem here c is initialized correctly in the constructor, just get rid of the super(); because its called implicitly by the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work in general; there is another problem with your actual code.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your comments, I now know that the above posted code is working and can narrow down the actual problem. Unfortunately I can't post the real code on here because it's just too large and complicated to be solved here ;)